# Editing the existing task in the task scheduler C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, taskscheduler

I am started working on Windows10 Task Scheduler .

I am developing GUI application in that I have requirement to control the number of days interval for trigger the task.

Suppose If I enter 5 days in my GUI then it should trigger the task in 5 days. Likewise randomly user can change the days.

Currently I have a task which is already exists in the task Scheduler, in that I need to control the days for to trigger in the User Interface.

I have seen the examples of Task Scheduler in MSDN but all of them are related to creating a new task or retrieving the states of existing task.

I don't want to create a new task , I want to edit the existing same task every time.

I didn't find anything which is related to editing the task which is already present in Task Scheduler.

Requesting anyone to please help me in editing the time trigger days in C++ using Task Scheduler 2.0.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like what you can do is get access to all the `ITrigger` instances that are defined for a given task. These provide you with [a pretty straightforward interface through which you set trigger times/limits/repetitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/taskschd/nn-taskschd-itrigger) etc. for the task.

You access these trigger objects through the [`ITaskDefinition`'s  `get_Triggers()` *method*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/taskschd/nf-taskschd-itaskdefinition-get_triggers), which returns an [`ITriggerCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/taskschd/nn-taskschd-itriggercollection) which you can iterate to find your trigger. You get the `ITaskDefinition` object by callng [`IRegisteredTask`'s `get_Definition()` *method*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/taskschd/nf-taskschd-iregisteredtask-get_definition). You get the `IRegisteredTask` object by calling [`ITaskFolder`'s `GetTask()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/taskschd/nf-taskschd-itaskfolder-gettask). An instance of which, to begin with, you get by calling [`ITaskService`'s `GetFolder()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/taskschd/nf-taskschd-itaskservice-getfolder). Few. Thank MS for this idea of an API.

If you need basic help finding headers and running code then there's a code example at the bottom of [this documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/TaskSchd/time-trigger-example--c---) that does something different than what you are requesting (it creates a new task, not accessing an existing one), but can provide you with all the necessary boilerplate snippets to get going.